# how to control the total memory of ray.serve?

Tags: python, memory, ray

I use `ray[serve]` as the server and send requests by `http`.
But after sending hours of requests, I found the memory of ray's actors is increasing continuously (over 90G for 20 actors). How can I control the total memory used by `ray`?

- OS: MacOS 10.15.7 / Linux Ubuntu 18 LTS
- Ray version: 1.7.0/1.4.1
- Python version: 3.7.11
- Installation:

```
cat requirements
> ray[serve]==1.7.0
> psutil
> requests

pip install -r requirements
```

The code for reproduction is as follows. I have tried `object_store_memory`, but it doesn't work for ray serve.

```py
import json
import os
import numpy as np
import psutil
import ray
import requests
from ray import serve


@serve.deployment(name="test_qps", route_prefix="/test_qps", ray_actor_options={"num_cpus": 1}, num_replicas=1)
class QpsTest:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def __call__(self, request):
        step_cnt = await request.json()
        state = np.random.randint(0, 255, (1000, 1000), np.uint64)

        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        proc_mem = process.memory_info().rss / (1024 ** 2)
        print(f'actor_pid={process.pid} \t mem={proc_mem:6.1f} MB.')
        return state


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ray.init(num_cpus=1, dashboard_host="0.0.0.0", object_store_memory=150_000_000)

    client = serve.start(http_options={"host": "0.0.0.0"})
    QpsTest.deploy()

    step_no = 5000000

    step_cnt = 0
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_qps"
    while step_cnt < step_no:
        req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(step_cnt))
        step_cnt += 1
        process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
        proc_mem = process.memory_info().rss / (1024 ** 2)
        print(f'main_pid={process.pid} \t mem={proc_mem:6.1f} MB.')
        print('-' * 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Am cross-posting the solution here, from [the Ray Discourse forum](https://discuss.ray.io):

This memory leak is not due to [Ray](https://ray.io), but to the third-party package `pytorch_forecasting`. The relative Github issue is *[Memory leak in TimeSeriesDataSet · Issue #648 · jdb78/pytorch-forecasting](https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting/issues/648)*.